# pptx converter to svg format to use with canvas

Tags: object, svg, powerpoint

I've developed some code to start reading an pptx file and now I need to convert this file to svg, i need all chart, shape, text, images to object so i can use with canvas. So, if anybody knows any package to do that with php or javascript, please suggest me about it.

I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/php/) for converting presentation slides to SVG images. The following code example shows you how to do this:

```php
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\Configuration;
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\SlidesApi;

$configuration = new Configuration();
$configuration->setAppSid("my_client_id");
$configuration->setAppKey("my_client_secret");

$slidesApi = new SlidesApi(null, $configuration);

// Convert a presentation to SVG images.
$fileStream = fopen("example.pptx", "r");
$response = $slidesApi->convert($fileStream, "svg");

print("A ZIP file with the slides as SVG images was saved to " . $response->getPathname());
```

Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK provides REST-based APIs for managing presentations. This is a paid product, but you can make 150 free API calls per month for evaluating all features and your purposes.

You can also use a free [Aspose Slides Online Converter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/conversion) for converting PowerPoint presentations to other formats. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.